# К какому типу ошибок относится слитное и раздельное написание союзов и предлогов?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, предлоги, союзы, частица

К какому типу ошибки относится слитное и раздельное написание союзов и предлогов?

Например (предложения с ошибкой!):

> **Что бы** сделать самокат, нужно два колеса и рама.
>
> **Чтобы** мне такого сделать! А?

Answer (score 3):

Такое написание относятся к типу орфографических ошибок, впрочем, как и любое неправильно написанное слово: будь то знаменательное или служебное слово.